# How to add support in Function List for a new user-defined language? (Notepad++ Win7 64bit)

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I'm writing in a user-defined language called 'Umajin' (*.u), which has a syntax quite different from C/C++ or any ECMAScript-based language, so we've had to write in the rules for the highlighting.

I've been trying to write parser rules for the language for function-list to pick up, too - but find that every time I try to add a rule through the dialog, it causes NP++ to crash.  This goes for the portable version as well as an install reading from %APPDATA%.   If I go into the FunctionListRules.xml and drop rules in for Umajin there, I can see them when I open the 'Language Parsing Rules' dialog, but they don't have any effect when viewing a .u file.

I have found, however, that if I clobber the settings for another existing language (I'm overwriting python, since it's closest in syntax), and then manually set the language to Python for any given file, the rules parse correctly and give me what I want.  The only problem being that I can have highlighting, or function listing, but not both!

Has anyone managed to drop parsing rules into Function List for an entirely new language?

For reference, I'm using Notepad++ 5.8 unicode and Function List 2.1 unicode, running on Win7 Enterprise and Ultimate.

Comment: Same question, now Im using last np++ version (at nov 2020), win10